# Does setTimeout delay the creation of the function?

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

This doesn't work because when "log" is being created while "message" doesn't exist.

```js
function x() {
  function log() {
    console.log(message)
  }
  const message = "hello"
   log()
}

x()
```

But this works? setTimeout isn't aware of the message and in my opinion, should throw an error. But it seems like the "log" is being created after "x" function is done executing? How is this explained?

```js
function x() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(message)
  }, 500)
  const message = "hello"
}

x()
```

Comment: The first one "doesn't work" because you never call `log()`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the event loop, and the fact that `setTimeout` takes a callback function as an argument.

Basically the order of operations are below

1. The function named x is defined
2. The function x is called
3. The function setTimeout is called
4. The constant variable named message is declared
5. The callback function that was passed as an argument to SetTimeout is called
6. The log method of the console object is called.

The first code snippet does not log to the console because your are not calling the function defined within function x.  You can log the variable to the console in the first code snippet by accessing the variable through a `closure`.

This should work with the first code snippet.

```js
function x() {
  const message = "hello"
  return function() {
    console.log(message)
  }

}

x()()
```

Another more simpler way, would be just to call the function within the function:

```js
function x() {
  function log() {
    console.log(message)
  }
  const message = "hello"
  log()
}

x()
```

Comment: What you've explained is absolutely correct. However, the question is not about how `timer` and `event-loop` work in JavaScript. It's one of those syntax error questions.

Comment: Sorry I meant to call log() in the first snippet. I just didn't understand why the second one worked because the variable is created after the callback is sent off to the settimeout

Comment: @Vehbi The function is not invoked until after the variable has been declared. That is why you do not get an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding what the first snippet of code is doing.

You are defining a function `x` which is defining a function `log` inside it and then setting a constant `message` to "hello";

At no point in the snippet does the `log` function get called, so the `console.log(message);` is never invoked.

In the second snippet you are using `setTimeout` to invoke a function which will run after 500ms.

Comment: Sorry I meant to call log() in the first snippet. I just didn't understand why the second one worked because the variable is created after the callback is sent off to the settimeout.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you did not call the `log()` function you created.
`setTimeout` function works because it executes the callback after given time.

```
function x() {
  function log() {
    console.log(message)
  }
  const message = "hello"

  log();
}

x()
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to call log() in the first snippet. I just didn't understand why the second one worked because the variable is created after the callback is sent off to the settimeout